# App Files on Mac OS X - Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have somehow gotten Visual Studio Code into an unusable state on Mac OS X. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it. However, that did not work. It looks like my user settings persisted though. Which means that there are some files or settings somewhere on Mac OS X.

Where do those files / settings get stored? I would like to remove them and start from scratch and see if that fixes my issue.

Thanks,

Comment: This question belongs to [apple.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vscode settings are in `~/.vscode`.

`rm -r ~/.vscode`

Should do the trick for you.